# Request for reference of cheat-sheet of paper concerning preprocessing and learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, data-preprocessing

Is there a comprehensive list of preprocessing steps that are highly recommended when using the classical learning algorithms (see below for a list of the families)?

Is there a cheat-sheet or a cook-book of when a certain preprocessing step is strongly recommended before applying the learning algorithms?

Is there one with recommendations which preprocessing rather not to do - as likely information is lost?

With preprocessing steps I think mainly of the classical ones in the context of numerical features (centering, scaling, PCA, BoxCox, outlier detection).

With learning algorithms I speak about the rather classical families as covered e.g. in [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/local.ftp/Springer/OLD/ESLII_print4.pdf) (families of tree methods, SVM, neural neworks and boosted models) or in Applied Predictive Modelling (p 550). There various preprocessing steps are already suggested. Nevertheless discussing them would be of interest.

Comment: @whuber would a question for a general reference - a cook book be ok ?

Comment: It would help to make the question more specific.  For instance, I suspect that each individual reading your post would have a different understanding of what "common ML-algorithms" means and they might all have a different sense of what "preprocessing" comprises.

Comment: @whuber I see. Do you think the reformulation as asking or a reference of a cheat-sheet is ok? Asking an "array" of 5 preprocessing procedures and 5 families is another solution. Which one do you think is better, thanks!

Comment: Concerning the "array," approach, questions that request lists of things are considered outside our scope.  Although plenty exist, they do so only in the face of considerable opposition.  All SE sites operate on the principle of ask-one-clear-question, get-one-good-answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to reformulate asking for a reference and adding some pieces of information which preprocessing operations I mean and which kind of learning algorithms I speak about.

Comment: "Certain models" is still far too broad. Recommended preprocessing steps will differ for different ML approaches. Even an entire ML textbook can't cover what you've asked for.

Comment: Ok, I delete the question. Thanks for your remarks.

Comment: I can not delete it. Please wither reopen it after my edit (the list in Max Kuhns book is perfect for my question and already gives parts of the answer) or delet it.

Answer (score 1):

Scaling prevents one feature from swamping the information learned from other features.  Mean-zero standardization and normalization in the range [0,1] are the most common.  Yes, artificial neural networks (ANNs) waste time learning the correlation between input features, if it exists, so PCA before use of ANNs is highly recommended.

For all of the classifiers listed, feature transformation should be performed prior to using any of the them.  You can also transform feature values into ranks, but there will be some bias due to ranks having a rectangular distribution.  Use of ranks and log-transforms removes outlier effects.